# Async walk_blobs throws "object AccessToken can't be used in 'await' expression"

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to asynchronously download blobs but even the very first step to list blobs throws exception. However listing blobs works if not asynchronous.

Using Python 3.7.6 on Windows 10 and installed Azure packages

```
azure-cli-core==2.2.0
azure-cli-nspkg==3.0.4
azure-cli-telemetry==1.0.4
azure-common==1.1.25
azure-core==1.2.1
azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.60.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==2.8.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault==2.2.0
azure-mgmt-resource==8.0.1
azure-mgmt-storage==9.0.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage-blob==12.1.0
```

Code sample to repro the issue

```py
import asyncio
import azure.storage.blob
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient


__account_url__ = "put your URL"
__container_name__ = "put your container"


async def main():
    client = get_client_from_cli_profile(
        ContainerClient,
        account_url=__account_url__,
        container_name=__container_name__
    )

    async with client:
        blob_list = [b async for b in client.walk_blobs()]

    return blob_list


def main_not_aysnc():
    client = get_client_from_cli_profile(
        azure.storage.blob.ContainerClient,
        account_url=__account_url__,
        container_name=__container_name__
    )

    with client:
        blob_list = [b for b in client.walk_blobs()]

    return blob_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    blob_list = asyncio.run(main())
    # blob_list = main_not_aysnc()
    for b in blob_list:
        print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieve items like this

```
  blob_list = []
        async for w in client.walk_blobs():
            blob_list.append(w)
```

instead of

```
 async with client:
        blob_list = [b async for b in client.walk_blobs()]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still throws the same exception. What is the reason it should not throw it?